# Não consigo acessar elemento checkbox do IE por vba

Tags: vba, checkbox, iframe, internet-explorer

Estou tentando clicar em uma checkbox pelo IE, usando VBA, porém não consigo acessar o elemento dessa checkbox.

Pesquisei em vários foruns distintos e o mais próximo que encontrei era que o acesso para uma parte da árvore poderia ser não permitido.

O site é: "http://www.bmfbovespa.com.br/pt_br/servicos/market-data/historico/mercado-de-derivativos/pesquisa-por-pregao/"

O checkbox é: input type="checkbox" id="chkArquivoDownload23_ativo" name="chkArquivoDownload_ativo" value="23" onclick="tratarSelecaoArquivo(event, this, '_ativo');" class="Mercado de Ações - Superfície de Volatilidade em Delta para opções sobre Ações" aria-invalid="false"

Segue meu código:

```
Sub download_IE()

Dim IE As Object
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

IE.Visible = True
IE.Navigate "http://www.bmfbovespa.com.br/pt_br/servicos/market-
data/historico/mercado-de-derivativos/pesquisa-por-pregao/"

Do While IE.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
Do While IE.ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

Dim elems As Object, e As Object


Set elems = IE.document.getelementsbytagname("iframe")
(0).contentWindow.document.getelementsbytagname("input")

For Each e In elems
    If e.getAttribute("id") = "chkArquivoDownload23_ativo" Then
        e.Click
    End If
Next e

End Sub
```

Comment: =] não se esqueça de marcar como resposta

Comment: Hector, vi que passou a ser membro da comunidade hoje, Logo abaixo da classificação da resposta, tem um V para marca-la como a resposta da sua questão. Por favor, marque-a. Obrigado

Answer (score 1):

usa a URL http://www.bmf.com.br/arquivos1/lum-arquivos_ipn.asp?idioma=pt-BR&status=ativo que dá origem ao frame que contém as checkBoxes,

se você só navegar para http://www.bmfbovespa.com.br/pt_br/servicos/market-data/historico/mercado-de-derivativos/pesquisa-por-pregao/ no código fonte não aparece a lista de CB

Comment: Rovann, genial!!! Resolveu, muitíssimo obrigado!!!

Comment: =] não se esqueça de marcar como resposta